# turn right vs turn to the right

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Is there any difference between "turn right" and "turn to the right"? Example:

> Turn (to the) right after the bridge.

Comment: There is a possible ambiguity.  “When do I turn left?” “Right [i.e. *immediately*] after the bridge.”

Answer (score 2):

There is not much difference.

"Turn right" when you are moving following a path. You are  moving forward and then you change your direction.

"Turn to the right" when you are not moving. You change the direction you are facing but don't start moving in that direction

But sometimes either could be used.

> Turn right after you pass the bridge
>
> If you turn to your right you will see the book.