# next turning on the right / next turning right / next turning to the right

Tags: phrase-usage

What's the difference?
I have found [this explanation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/223500/turn-right-vs-turn-to-the-right). Is it possible to use the third sentence, when you are driving the car and have stopped your car somewhere? Please, explain these three sentences.

> Take the next turning **on the right**.
>
> Take the next turning **right**.
>
> Take the next turning **to the right**.

Comment: None of these are idiomatic.  **Turning** means "the action of making a turn", so it doesn't make sense: there is not an action down the road on the right!  We would take "take the next **turn** on the right" or even just "take the next right."

Comment: @stangdon: In this dictionary it's possible. https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/turning

Comment: True, that's what that dictionary says, but I have never heard anyone say it in all my life in the US.

Comment: @Sergey, I agree with stangdon. It is not grammatically incorrect to say turning, but it is not idiomatic... in British English too.

Comment: @stangdon It may not be common in the US, but here in the UK "take the next turning"  is common usage (rather than "...next turn") and I've heard and used it often. I fear this is yet another subtle difference between UK and US English.

Comment: Do I not live on the same planet as you guys? Accordig to [***this NGram***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28take+the+next+turn+left%29%2B%28take+the+next+turn+right%29%2C%28take+the+next+turning+left%29%2B%28take+the+next+turning+right%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28take%20the%20next%20turn%20left%29%20%2B%20%28take%20the%20next%20turn%20right%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28take%20the%20next%20turning%20left%29%20%2B%20%28take%20the%20next%20turning%20right%29%3B%2Cc0) (and my own speech), ***turn*** and ***turning*** are equally used.

Comment: I have to agree with @PeterJennings - all three of these are acceptable in the UK. The first form is EXACTLY what you would hear on a driving test. Second form is unusual, probably only encountered in spoken language.

Comment: Obviously there's ***no possibility whatsoever*** that "turn" and "turning" could have different ***meanings*** in this context. And I personally would quite happily switch from one to the other every time I spoke. How can so many people think one or the other is either "not used" or has some different nuance?

Comment: BUT see [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28next+turn+on+the+left%29%2B%28next+turn+on+the+right%29%2C%28next+turning+on+the+left%29%2B%28next+turning+on+the+right%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10) showing that if ***left/right*** is preceded by [optional] ***on the***, both Brits and Americans are *far* more likely to use ***turning*** rather than ***turn***.

Comment: FINALLY, compare [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28next+turn+to+the+left%29%2B%28next+turn+to+the+right%29%2C%28next+turning+to+the+left%29%2B%28next+turning+to+the+right%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10) to the previous, to see that *turn/turnings **to** the left/right* only occur half as often as those ***on** the left/right*.

Comment: I've never heard any of these in the US. I'm not impressed by Google anything (they're a duplicitous company to put it mildly), and "on the left turning" unless it's part of some larger phrase **just isn't used** in the US. I can't even imagine when you'd say "on the left turning", lol.