# Difference between 'Turn right', 'turn to the right', and 'turn to his/her right'

Tags: difference

Difference between 'turn right', 'turn to the right', and 'turn to his/her right'.

I read [this post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/223500/turn-right-vs-turn-to-the-right#:%7E:text=There%20is%20not%20much%20difference,then%20you%20change%20your%20direction.&text=But%20sometimes%20either%20could%20be%20used) already, but it refers to giving indications.

My question refers to another situation. Let's imagine a man is sitting on a bench. Then another man comes and sits beside him on his right. If the first man turns to see who sat beside him, what will we say?

> A) The man **turned right** to see who had sat beside him.
>
> B) The man **turned to his right** to see who had sat beside him.
>
> C) The man **turned to the right** to see who had sat beside him.

Needless to say, if there are better options to describe this action, do let me know!

Comment: I would say he 'looked round' (if we already know that the newcomer is on his right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All are possible...but...

"Turned right" and "Turned to the right" suggest that the man was moving, and his path went right.

"Turned to his right", by making it relative to "him", doesn't suggest moving along a path, so might be better.  I might prefer "looked to his right" too.

Comment: He could _turn his head to the right_, or _look (or glance) to his right_. It is impolite (at least where I live) to stare at strangers.

Comment: I'm not convinced the *change direction of **moving / looking*** distinction turns on whether it's ***the** right* or ***his** right*, so much as it turns on whether or not we include the preposition ***to***. That's to say *He turned right* usually implies he changed *direction*, where *He turned **to** the/his right* more likely implies he looked to that side. But these are usage *tendencies* - they don't prevent native speakers from reversing those meanings.

Comment: Thats probably worth an alternate answer

Answer (score 1):

In OP's context it's an irrelevant stylistic choice whether to use ***his** right* or ***the** right* (but a quick check with Google Books suggests ***the*** is *slightly* more common).

The *change direction of **moving / looking*** distinction isn't affected by whether it's ***the** right* or ***his** right*. The relevant tendency there is...

> ***He turned right***
> = *He changed **direction** [of travel]*
> ***He turned to the / his right***
> = *He **looked** to one side [turning his neck/torso]*

Note that this is a usage *tendency,* not a "rule". The intended sense is usually contextually obvious anyway, but nothing prevents competent native speakers from reversing the above distinction in any given case.

---

TL;DR: OP's first alternative is relatively unlikely / stylistically weak. The second and third alternatives are equivalent and interchangeable.

Comment: Could it be that 'turned to the right' is more common because it can be used with also female and plural pronouns? I wish I could test that on ngram, but right now it's not working.

Comment: No, that *couldn't* be a factor! Native Anglophones have never cared much about linguistic gender. We're had genderless "singular they" since before Shakespeare's time, and we've never assigned gender to nouns like other European languages. But that's because *Anglophones aren't interested in such matters*, not because English was into woke anti-sexist language centuries before the rest of the world!